# how to echo currentdate in mysql query php

Tags: php, mysql, date

current month start

```
<?php echo date("Y-m-1");?>
```

current month end

```
<?php echo date("Y-m-31");?>


and this is mysql query

$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM fuel where monthdate BETWEEN 'current month start' AND 'current month end' ORDER BY CAST(amount as SIGNED INTEGER) DESC LIMIT 4");
```

how to echo this to

```
<?php echo date("Y-m-1");?>

   <?php echo date("Y-m-31");?>
```

in this
BETWEEN '{Y-m-1}' AND '{Y-m-31}'

please help me to fix this issue 
thanks

Comment: You do realise that not every month has 31 days?

Comment: What type is your monthdate column?

Comment: yes i knw but 31 is last date if month have 30 days so its not a big problem it is showing to month start to month end 31 if 31 date is not there then its is showing 30 days result

Comment: Date functions don't work that way. Try this in an SQL query: `SELECT DATE('2013-02-28'), DATE('2013-02-31')` It will return `2013-02-28` and `NULL`. MySQL expects a VALID date, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: `<?php echo date("Y-m-t");?>` will give you the last day of the month.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need to find the current year and  month record you can use `EXTRACT` function of mysql which gives you current month  and perform `=` comparison

```
SELECT * FROM fuel where 
EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM `monthdate`) =
EXTRACT(YEAR_MONTH FROM CURRENT_DATE) 
ORDER BY CAST(amount as SIGNED INTEGER) 
DESC LIMIT 4
```

Note make sure column `monthdate` datatype is proper like `date,datetime`

[**EXTRACT**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_extract)

Comment: @user2468472 Please refer to this **Note make sure column monthdate datatype is proper like date,datetime**

Answer (score 1):

You can do that easily in pure SQL, without hassling with time in PHP:

```
"SELECT * FROM fuel WHERE YEAR(monthdate) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND MONTH(monthdate) = MONTH(CURDATE()) ORDER BY CAST(amount as SIGNED INTEGER) DESC LIMIT 4"
```

Also, you can't expect invalid dates to work like this.

Try this in an SQL query:

```
`SELECT DATE('2013-02-28'), DATE('2013-02-31')`
```

It will return `2013-02-28` and `NULL`. MySQL expects a VALID date, otherwise it will not work.

Comment: Is `monthdate` a date field?

Answer (score 0):

Use date_format if you need to select everything from a given month:

```
$myDate = date('Y-m');
$sql = "SELECT * FROM `fuel` WHERE DATE_FORMAT('%Y-%m', `monthdate`) = '$myDate'";
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code woking fine.

```
$result = mysql_query(
    "SELECT * FROM fuel where monthdate BETWEEN (SELECT DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) , '%Y-%m-1' )) AND (SELECT DATE_FORMAT( NOW( ) , '%Y-%m-30' )) ORDER BY CAST(amount as SIGNED INTEGER) DESC LIMIT 4"
);
```